# Question about function format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, datepicker

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and I'm working with JavaScript's datePicker library.  I'm pretty much using the code out of the box, and the function that reads in the current date selected has me a bit confused.  Here's the code (which I've modified slightly to format the date - in order to string-match it to the dates of my dataset).

```
const picker = datepicker(document.querySelector('#inlineDatepicker'), {

  // Event callbacks.
  onSelect: function(instance) {
  console.log(instance)
  var instanceSplit = instance.dateSelected.toString().split(" " ,4)
  var instanceClean = instanceSplit.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ')
    if (instanceClean === 'Mon Feb 11 2019') {
            console.log('datematch!')
            return 'blue'
        }       
      },
   });
```

I'm not familiar with the format of the `onSelect: function(instance) {}` function.  All the functions I've ever seen are written in this format: `function someFunction(parameter) {}`.

Which leads me to my question: what is the actual function name of the `onSelect: function(instance) {}` function?  For example, if I want to change the appearance of my data based on the date selected - i.e. return a stroke of 'blue' on my data points - what function name do I call?  For example, the code here attempts to pass in the returned stroke value in the above function, but it doesn't recognize onSelect as a function (says it's undefined):

```
var events = mapG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(allSFEvents)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", onSelect)
```

Comment: The `datepicker` is a method of jQuery UI, or you may have some other library going on there, from the way you're calling it. JavaScript is a language, not a component library (indeed, it is not restricted to browsers). Regarding your code; it doesn't make a lot of sense to return a color name from an `onSelect` event handler (which is a property of the object you're passing to the `datepicker` function).

Comment: What is it that you would expect `.style("stroke", onSelect)` to mean even?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "name", that function either doesn't have a name (it's *anonymous*), which is the strict meaning according to the definition of the language; or else the "name" in colloquial terms is the name of the property to which it's assigned.

The problem with the colloquial meaning, that the name is the property name, is that it can lead to false assumptions about the relationship between the anonymous function and the object where that property lives. There's *no* permanent relationship, in fact; the anonymous function is free of any implicit association with any "parent" object.

In your case, it's unlikely that you'd ever want to *directly* call that function. It's set up as an event handler, which means that the runtime or some framework will invoke your function at the appropriate time. In general, if an object property refers to a function, you can call that function via the property:

```
var someObject = {
  someFunction: function() { alert("Hi!"); }
};

someObject.someFunction(); // alerts "Hi!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Let me simplify my question: I think what I'm trying to do is just use that onSelect function to return the current date so I can use it outside of the function.                                                                                                         
  `var selectedDate
     

  var selectedDate

  onSelect: function(instance) {

    var instanceSplit = instance.dateSelected.toString().split(" " ,4)
   
    var instanceClean = instanceSplit.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ')
 
    selectedDate = instanceClean

    return selectedDate
  }, });`

Comment: Well that's a *different* issue: a function used as an event handler in any typical JavaScript context doesn't "return" *anything*. There are definitely a few exceptions, but by and large those are about controlling the event processing mechanisms and not about communicating application data from one place to another.

Comment: Ok. How do I go about returning the date then?  I want to use the date selected in other sections of my code.

Comment: If an event handler captures some information, it can store it in some accessible data store for use when the next event handler needs it. Events, by their very nature, happen when they happen.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 what I'm trying to say is that the way you're asking that question *does not make sense*.  Your event handler can call some other function and pass information to it, or it can save the information somewhere. The term "return" is about *synchronous* calls to functions, and that's simply not what an event handler is about.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, I think I want to save the information somewhere.  As in, a global variable that will continually be updated as the selected date changes.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes *that* makes sense. Now understand that because events happen when they happen, you have to check to see if a value is actually available at the point you go to use it.